# Debugging channels in "goland"

Tags: channel, goland

is there a way to watch the content of a **channel** in **goland debug mode**?
I tried the debug mode and cannot get the result.

Comment: Hello Alex, please, provide more details to the question. It'd be useful if you post a code example, where you set a breakpoint, what do you want to see in debug mode and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is under the `buf` field of a channel. So add your watch being `<channel>.buf`. This assumes the channel is buffered. You cannot watch a non-buffered channel in the same way.

[image]